# Mac Mail Archive folder suddenly nonfunctional

Tags: mail.app, email, gmail, archive

Using gmail address through mac mail on imac OS 13.4.1, firefox browser.

A couple days ago, I am suddenly unable to "archive" items from the inbox. When I try, they just all pop back into the inbox. I can "delete" but not "archive."

This is new. Nothing has changed on my system lately. Anyone have insight?

Comment: Are you using the Mail app or the Firefox browser to see your emails? Is the problem with gmail.com (online) or with the Mail app?

Comment: Using the Mail app. Just tried going straight in through gmail and the archive folder works from there as usual.